# What instrument is used in the background?

Tags: instruments

What instrument is being used to create the soft "pulsating" background noise in this video. It almost sounds like some sort of strings but I am not sure.

For example, between timestamp 37s to 46s I hear the vocals, piano and then this pulsating noise.

[The Tenors - Forever Young](https://youtu.be/m5hOypcvB1s)